# Creating an aspect on a spring @Controller with @Autowired final fields in constructor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an aspect setup

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class JsonAspect {

    @Around("execution(public au.com.mycompany.common.json.response.JsonResponse *(..)) " +
            "&& @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public final Object beforeMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws JsonException {
        try {
            System.out.println("before...................");
            System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new JsonException(t);
        }

    }
}
```

I this should apply to a `@Controller` class with the following method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public final JsonResponse<JsonValidationResponse> validateViaJson(...
```

The problem is that I am injecting dependencies via `@Autowired`

```
private final ClientService clientService;
private final VehicleService vehicleService;

@Autowired
public QuoteControllerImpl(
        final ClientService clientService,
        final VehicleService vehicleService,
        ) {
    this.clientService = clientService;
    this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
}
```

When I try to proxy this class it complains that there is no default constructor.  so I decided to crate an interface for the class but now I get the following error on an unrelated method in the same class.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of
>   declaring class

The above error applies to a method that is is in the same class but not part of the aspectj pointcut.  If remove the aspectj pointcut it works (event with the new interface).  So it seems that aspectj proxy is causing a problem somehow.

Anyone know why?

### UPDATE

@nicholas.hauschild I tried your solution but now I am getting a NullPointer Exception when I initialise my map.

```
@ModelAttribute
public final void initialiseModel(final ModelMap map, @PathVariable("status") final String status) {
        map.addAttribute(CLIENTS, clientService.getClients());
```

**clientService** is null.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a huge fan of this solution, but if you create the default constructor along with the `@Autowired` one, Spring will use the `@Autowired`one anyways.

```
private final ClientService clientService;
private final VehicleService vehicleService;

@Autowired
public QuoteControllerImpl(
        final ClientService clientService,
        final VehicleService vehicleService,
        ) {
    this.clientService = clientService;
    this.vehicleService = vehicleService;
}

public QuoteControllerImpl() {
    //Spring won't use me...
    this.clientService = null;
    this.vehicleService = null;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting a NullPointer Exception on my ModelMap (see updated question)